# Dynamic spinner value from MySQL database

Tags: android

I am trying to set spinner value dynamically. The values will be fetched from MySql database and it will shown in the spinner. Following is my code till now. Please let me know what are my mistakes.

My JSON response

```
    {
        "result": [
        {
            "sl": "1",
            "lvl_name": "admin",
            "lvl_id": "10"
        },
        {
            "sl": "2",
            "lvl_name": "Moderator",
            "lvl_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "sl": "3",
            "lvl_name": "Teacher",
            "lvl_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "sl": "4",
            "lvl_name": "Student",
            "lvl_id": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

My JAVA code which I am using to fetch data.

```
public void getSpinnerData(){

    connUrl = "http://192.168.1.102/cms/spinner.php";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(connUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            arrayList.add(json.getString(TAG_USERNAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    lvl_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


}
```

Data is not shown in the spinner. It is not working. Please help.